# Migrate MySQL database to Sql Server

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server

I recently encountered a problem in my production database due to MySQL bug. The bug is in the TimeStamp column. To avoid any inconvenience, I want to migrate the database to either Sql Server.

Is there any FREE tool to easily and reliably migrate data and table structures?

Comment: what do you mean with 'either' SQL server? Do you mean 'another', or do you specifically want to migrate to the PAID tool Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Of course this is a valid question, but I don't like the introduction - i would have preferred if you left out your reasons for switching platforms. Alternatively you could specify exactly which bug you are talking about, most likely there is a workaround, if it actually is a bug (random fact: google search on 'mysql timestamp bug' return 4 times less results then 'mssql timestamp bug').

Comment: Sorry for the same. Please ignore that "either". Actually I was thinking of Oracle also, but it needs a dedicated DBA.

Comment: @Unreason: Since the time Oracle acquired MySQL, I am not seeing much on MySQL website. If you are unhappy with SQL Server, can you suggest any other less buggy alternative?

Comment: not unhappy with mssql, i consider db2, mysql, oracle, mssql and postgres mostly equivalent; my point was in questioning the move. To reiterate - what is this TimeStamp bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://blogs.technet.com/b/dataplatforminsider/archive/2010/01/11/free-download-microsoft-sql-server-migration-assistant.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I would think twice about migrating to a new platform, before you have assessed all the pros and cons of making such a step.

For example you could ask yourself:

- What is the difference in cost between the old and the new product?
- How much work is involved in the migration (eg. do you have any SQL code that has to be rewritten in the new SQL dialect: stored functions, stored procedures, triggers and the like)
- Could I spend the same or less money/work by hiring an experienced DBA that can provide a workaround to the MySQL timestamp bug

When you have made an informed decision and you still want to migrate to a new platform, I can recommend Microsoft SQL Server. As far as I know, it is cheaper than Oracle, and it is a stable platform without any blatant bugs and a wide (if not the widest) community of users - so finding solutions to problems is easy.

And in that case, you can use the migration tool mentioned by FractalizeR.